# Passar DataTable para um table-valued parameter num stored procedure em SQL não funciona

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datatable, stored-procedures

Eu estou a criar um site de receitas. Na minha MasterPage (estou a trabalhar em ASP.net), tenho um ícone de procura e quando o utilizador clica nesse ícone, eu vou ler três checkboxlists e passar os valores seleccionados de cada checkboxlist para um DataTable.

A ideia é passar esse DataTable como um parâmetro para um stored procedure que mais tarde me devolverá as receitas que cumpram os critérios presentes no DataTable. Apesar de o código estar a funcionar em termos estruturais, nenhum resultado é mostrado.

**Stored Procedure e Table Type SQL**

```
 CREATE TYPE dbo.Filtros AS TABLE
(
    Categoria NVARCHAR(50),
    Dificuldade NVARCHAR(50),
    Duracao NVARCHAR(50)
);
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspPesquisarReceita] (@TVP dbo.Filtros READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT R.NomeReceita, C.NomeCategoria, DF.Dificuldade, D.Duracao, R.ClassificacaoGeral, R.DataPublicacao, R.Foto, R.NumVisualizacoes, R.IDReceita
        FROM dbo.Receitas R 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Categorias C ON R.IDCategoria = C.IDCategoria
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Dificuldade DF ON R.IDDificuldade = DF.IDDificuldade
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Duracao D ON R.IDDuracao = D.IDDuracao
        WHERE R.IDEstado = 1 AND (C.NomeCategoria IN (SELECT Categoria FROM @TVP) OR DF.Dificuldade IN (SELECT Dificuldade FROM @TVP) OR D.Duracao IN (SELECT Duracao FROM @TVP))
END
```

**C# para preencher o TVP passado como parâmetro para Stored Procedure**

```
public DataTable verFiltros()
        {
            DataTable dtFiltros = new DataTable();
            dtFiltros.Columns.Add("Categoria", typeof(string));
            dtFiltros.Columns.Add("Dificuldade", typeof(string));
            dtFiltros.Columns.Add("Duracao", typeof(string));

            foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dtFiltros.NewRow();
                    dr["Categoria"] = item;
                    dtFiltros.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }

            foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList2.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dtFiltros.NewRow();
                    dr["Dificuldade"] = item;
                    dtFiltros.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }

            foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList3.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dtFiltros.NewRow();
                    dr["Duracao"] = item;
                    dtFiltros.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }

            return dtFiltros;
        }
```

**C# do Stored Procedure e da DataTable utilizada para guardar as receitas que o Stored Procedure deve devolver**

```
public SqlDataReader receitaPesquisada(DataConnection conn, DataTable tabelaParam)
        {
            SqlDataReader drObterReceita = null;

            try
            {
                string strCmmd = "uspPesquisarReceita";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strCmmd, conn.Connection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@TVP", tabelaParam);
                param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                param.TypeName = "dbo.Filtros";
                command.Parameters.Add(param);


                drObterReceita = command.ExecuteReader();

                return drObterReceita;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write("Algo correu mal no método" + ex.ToString());

                return drObterReceita;
            }
        }

        public DataTable imprimirReceitaPesquisada(DataTable tabelaParam)
        {
            DataConnection conn = new DataConnection();

            DataTable dtbReceitaPesquisada = new DataTable();

            dtbReceitaPesquisada.Columns.Add("NomeReceita", typeof(string));
            dtbReceitaPesquisada.Columns.Add("Categoria", typeof(string));
            dtbReceitaPesquisada.Columns.Add("Dificuldade", typeof(string));
            dtbReceitaPesquisada.Columns.Add("Duracao", typeof(string));
            dtbReceitaPesquisada.Columns.Add("ClassificacaoGeral", typeof(string));
            dtbReceitaPesquisada.Columns.Add("DataPublicacao", typeof(string));
            dtbReceitaPesquisada.Columns.Add("Foto", typeof(string));
            dtbReceitaPesquisada.Columns.Add("NumVisualizacoes", typeof(string));

            try
            {
                conn.openConnection();

                SqlDataReader drObterReceita = this.receitaPesquisada(conn, tabelaParam);

                while (drObterReceita.Read())
                {
                    dtbReceitaPesquisada.Rows.Add(drObterReceita[0].ToString(), drObterReceita[1].ToString(), drObterReceita[2].ToString(), drObterReceita[3].ToString(), Math.Round(double.Parse(drObterReceita[4].ToString()), 1).ToString(), drObterReceita[5].ToString(), drObterReceita[6].ToString(), drObterReceita[7].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write("Algo correu mal no método" + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.closeConnection();
            }
            return dtbReceitaPesquisada;
        }
```

**Code Behind da página ASP.net que deve mostrar o resultado da pesquisa (e que actualmente não devolve nada)**

```
public partial class aspnet_ResultadoPesquisa : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Receitas novaReceita = new Receitas();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                DataList();
            }
        }

        public void DataList()
        {
            DataTable dtReceitas = new DataTable();
            dtReceitas = novaReceita.imprimirReceitaPesquisada(Master.verFiltros());
            DataList1.DataSource = dtReceitas;
            DataList1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: a sua contrução está estranha, sua table tem 3 colunas, mas só preenche uma de cada vez, na prática está passando 3 listas e não uma linha de tabela, essa construção é meio sem sentido. Poderia criar um tipo com apenas 1 coluna com NVARCHAR(50), e a procedure receber 3 paramentros desse tipo `(@categoria dbo.Filtros, @dificuldade dbo.Filtros, @duracao dbo.Filtros)` o que faria mais sentido, por causa dos 3 `foreach` e o `where` ficaria mais claro. Ou seria ainda mais fácil passar 3 parametros de `NVARCHAR`, pq na verdade seu código passa só 1 valor para cada combo, o selecionado

Comment: para chamar a procedure está complicando demais algo que seria muito simples :)

Comment: Olá @RicardoPontual! Estou a ver. Uma boa ideia com a questão de usar apenas uma coluna no Type. De facto, apenas preciso de uma coluna com todos os valores seleccionados e depois procurar sempre na mesma. No entanto, a questão de usar apenas 3 parâmetros não é viável, porque o utilizador pode seleccionar mais que uma opção em cada checkboxlist1 (não tenho forma de saber quantas ao todo). Por isso, preciso mesmo de um table valued parameter. Mas q questão de criar apenas uma coluna parece interessante!

Comment: Como poderia melhorar o chamar o procedure?

Comment: percebi a ideia, então precisa ser mesmo uma table, mas acho que fica mais simples se passar 3 parametros do tipo table, um para cada "checkbox". O restante do código me parece bem, só capturando o comando no SQL para ver qual o problema, talvez usando o sql profiler

Comment: Ah quanto ao problema. Entretanto, eu já resolvi :) o problema era que eu estava a preencher o TVP com um método quando o utilizador clicava num botao de "Procurar". A questão e q esse botao redirecciona para outra pagina, então quando eu chamava o método nessa outra página, a DataTable vinha vazia porque as checkboxlist nao tinham nada devido ao PostBack. Quando passei o DataTable para uma variável Session isso já resolveu! Obrigado pela ajuda, e pela sugestão, vou experimentar ;)